# From where are these null bytes appearing?

Tags: php, session, cookies, null, mcrypt

For an API test suite I am using the following code to save the user's password encrypted:

```
$encryptionKey = sha1(microtime(true) . mt_rand(PHP_INT_MAX / 10, PHP_INT_MAX));
setcookie('key', $encryptionKey, 0);

$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['encryptedPassword'] = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryptionKey, $_POST['password'], MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

To retrieve the password, I am using the following code:

```
$password = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $_COOKIE['key'], $_SESSION['encryptedPassword'], MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

It appears that sometimes five null bytes are appended to the value stored. Thus, `var_dump($password)` returns the following:

```
string(8) "123"
```

`var_export($password)` returns the following:

```
'123' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . ''
```

Note that we see **three** characters, yet `var_dump()` insists that there are **eight**. Right now I am using `trim()` to work around this issue, but I would like to know how to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most encryption algorithms (this one included) work on fixed block sizes, typically of 8 bytes. So the value that is actually encoded in this case *is* `123\0\0\0\0\0` (which is actually slightly unusual, many encryption algorithms use the padding size as the padding - e.g. `123\5\5\5\5\5`)

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing mode from [ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) to more secure mode like [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). To remove padding you can use rtrim($decryptedtext, "\0"). Look at [example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php). This is default 0 padding, as mentioned before, encryption data is padded with 0 to match size of block. You can add PKCS7 padding before encrypting you can find examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php).